# Fragment losing content XAMARIN

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a doubt, where I have 3 fragments inside an activity, the moment each fragment and activated it always refreshes, I want it to give the update at the moment the 'i = 0'. I tried to do this but the fragment returns everything to me blank, it does not load anything to me with this doubt if I always have to update the fragment in its selection. My application does not have to be updated at all times only when i = 0. It works perfectly so I do not want it to update at all times and it is not necessary

```
 public class Fragment2 : SupportFragment
{
    private List<FeedItem> lista;
    private ListView feedItemsListView;
    public int i;


    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment2, container, false);

        this.feedItemsListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView2);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            this.GetFeedItemsList();
            i = 1;
        }
        return view;
    }


    private void GetFeedItemsList()
    {
       this.progressDialog.Show();

        Task<List<FeedItem>> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                                           {
            return FeedService.GetFeedItems("url");
        }
        );

        Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
                                        {
            try
            {
                this.progressDialog.Dismiss();
                this.lista = antecedent.Result;
                this.PopulateListView(this.lista);
            }
            catch (AggregateException aex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText (this, aex.InnerException.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        );
    }

    private void PopulateListView(List<FeedItem> feedItemsList)
    {
        var adapter = new FeedItemsListAdapter(Activity, feedItemsList);
        this.feedItemsListView.Adapter = adapter;
        this.feedItemsListView.ItemClick += OnListViewItemClick;
    }

    protected void OnListViewItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Obviously you still should call `PopulateListView`

Comment: Yes, obviously I need to call it only the first time to load the list. The other times that I access do not need to load it has to stay saved that list

Comment: loading is done in task1 ... Obviously there is no need to call it again if lista is not null

Comment: Then there is my problem, it is null at all times, and only I leave the fragment when I return in it it is null

Comment: By "I have 3 fragments inside an activity, the moment each fragment and activated it always refreshes,", do you mean you have three fragments share the same class `Fragment2`?

Comment: I have 3 fragments within a MainActivity